# ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, android-fragments

**In the line ::**

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

**I am getting error as::**
***`ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type`***

### My MainActivity

```
    public class ActLogin extends ActionBarActivity {

        String className;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.act_login);
            //set
            //Set the color for Actionbar
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.windhya_actionbar_color)));

            //Hide Appicon
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);

            //First fragment should be mounted on oncreate of main activity
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {  

                Fragment newFragment = FrgLogin.newInstance();  
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
                ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment).addToBackStack(FrgLogin.class.getSimpleName()).commit();  
            }

        }

  .....
```

---

### Fragment class

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.windhyaworks.R;
import com.windhyaworks.activities.ActMain;
import com.windhyaworks.utils.CommonFunctions;
import com.windhyaworks.utils.DlgUniversalError;
import com.windhyaworks.utils.JSONParser;

public class FrgLogin extends Fragment{

    FragmentTransaction ft = null;
    Button btnLoginId;
    EditText edtPhnoId;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private static String errMsg=null;
    private static boolean isErr=false;

    boolean isVendor=false;
    String phoneNumber="NoValue";
    String authCode="NoValue";
    String otpCode="NoValue";

    String loginMsg,loginStatus;
    private ProgressDialog prg;

    boolean isServerResponsive=false;

    public static FrgLogin newInstance(){
        Log.d(FrgLogin.class.getSimpleName(), "newInstance");
        FrgLogin fragment = new FrgLogin();
        return  fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Make sure the keyboard only pops up when a user clicks into an EditText
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); 



        //Hide icon from navigation drawer.
        //getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_login, container, false);

        btnLoginId=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLoginId);
        edtPhnoId=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtPhnoId);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIi"); 
        ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

.....
```

Comment: did you added the library to the same workspace or directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import it from `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`. as the package name shows, you need the support-v7 package.